# Embedded Brisk? Is it possible?

Tags: cassandra, hive, brisk

I'm just getting ramped up on a new application and have decided to try out / learn Cassandra and use it for the back end.

I've got embedded Cassandra working like a charm. Now I want to add Hive on top. Has anyone attempted embedded Brisk (from DataStax) before?

Is this even possible with all the moving parts??

Thanks!

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. The biggest impediments would be:

- Dependency management
- JVM sizing and tunning
- Workload isolation/service segmentation